# ASP.net evitar ir atras en explorador, y evitar presionar dos veces el mismo boton

Tags: asp.net

tengo un inconveniente, muchas veces los usuarios presionan el botón dos veces y eso causa inconsistencia de datos, o bien presionan una, van atrás y vuelven a presionar el botón, entonces las preguntas claves son: ¿Como evitar mas de un click en un boton? ¿como evitar que se pueda ir atrás en una página web?

Answer (score 2):

Para deshabilitar el botón puedes apoyarte de jQuery, un ejemplo rápido:

```
$(document).ready(function){
    $('#idBoton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Para tu otra cuestión podrías tratar de usar esto:

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```